# Zabbix key with comma

Tags: sql, zabbix

I'm trying to create Zabbix item with key which contains commas, it results with "Too many parameters." error. I don't see any opportunity to get rid off comma in my key. I've already tried many ways of enclosing key or parts of it in quotes, double quotes etc. but nothing worked for me. I don't want to use "Database monitor" item type, I'd like to stay with simple "Zabbix agent".

My key is

```
system.run[sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME-q "SELECT Count(Datediff(second, mail_tsinsert, mail_tsupdate)) FROM  TABLENAME WHERE Datediff(second, mail_tsinsert, mail_tsupdate) > 200"]
```

of course I've changed the servername and tablename for the sake of the example, query works like a charm when executed in cmd.

Is there a way to escape zabbix item keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with multiple square brackets, like this:

```
system.run[[sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME-q "SELECT Count(Datediff(second, mail_tsinsert, mail_tsupdate)) FROM   TABLENAME WHERE Datediff(second, mail_tsinsert, mail_tsupdate) > 200"]]
```